# How to let upload huge files in my domain?

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, appdomain

Hello I have a laravel app and it works perfectly I change this:

```
post_max_size=40M
upload_max_filesize=40M
```

but when I publish the app I put this in my manage php:

[image]
but don't work. what can I do?

PD: I know that I dont have to upload huge files, but it's only a test.
PD2: Sorry for my english.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there any errors?

Comment: In addition to your PHP ini settings, you should also check to be sure your web server (e.g., Nginx, Apache) is configured to allow large file uploads. What web server do you use?

Comment: I use apache, but I dont know what can I change, cause I dont change this in local only change the php.ini

Comment: What do you mean by `huge`? What is the exact size..

Comment: 48MB or little more